# How would demi-conditionals work?

Tags: symbolic-logic, translation, formalisation, truth-conditional-semantics, non-classical-logic

Let  = an actuality operator and √→ be demi-if. Which, if any, of the following conversions would go through?

1. *A* √→ *B* = √*A* → √*B*
2. *A* √→ *B* = √*A* → *B*
3. *A* √→ *B* = *A* → √*B*
4. *A* √→ *B* = √*A* √→ √*B*

I haven't come up with any other variations on the theme; moreover, I've hardly any idea how to compute truth-tables for demi-operations. Offhand, I assume (4) is wrong as a conversion, although the right-hand expression *could* occur on its own terms for some other reason. For general reasons of symmetry, I intuitively am gravitating towards (1), except that for reasons of "paradoxes" of material implication, I wonder about the viability of (2) and (3) (as reformulations of some natural-language uses of conditional operations).

**P.S.** I promise that I won't try to provide an answer to this question myself, at least since my intuitions seem to be half-failing (demi-failing!) me quite extensively, here.

---

**Corollary addendum:**

The [classical deduction theorem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-substructural/#1) goes:

> *p*, *q* ⊢ *r* if and only if *p* ⊢ *q* → *r*

Now if demi-if is "real" (pragmatistically admissible, or useful, or whatever along the intended line...), it is open for us to ask what would happen if the demi-conditional appeared in residuation. *A priori*, we suppose that the demi-conditional does *implicitly* appear twice in the quoted theorem, but what if it appeared alone? How would this influence the analysis of substructural logic? For I have earlier taken the proof turnstile for demi-*truth* already, rotated from the downtack angle appropriately. So however demi-actuality interfaces with demi-conditionality should affect how demi-proof interfaces with demi-conditionality in turn, here.

Comment: In some substructural logics such as relevance logic, your addended deduction theorem may not hold any more if q is not relevant to r. Maybe you can find its 'relevance' to your 'demi-conditional'...

Comment: @DoubleKnot bit of a stream of consciousness subquestion here, but since residuation is compared to the same re: subtraction, and division is/can be iterated subtraction, is any of this relevant to what I said in an earlier post about substructural logic issues as potentially useful in "describing" the Continuum? Because I also was thinking: the square root of 2 is the "first" irrational number to arise in the normal progression of the hyperoperator sequence, so my intuition is itching to find out whether all this might play into approaching 2nd-order arithmetic's proof-theoretic ordinal...

Comment: FWIW, the notation I saw in Rathjen's discussion of how Gentzen identified PA's PTO also inspired this subquestion, since the template looks equivalent to the template of the deduction theorem, sans one premise in the presentation.